# How to fix "ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', the service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'."

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting a strange error in my docker-compose.yml file.
I am trying create a instance of "Seafile".

Below is the docker-compose.yml file

```sh
version: '2.0'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    container_name: seafile-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=11111111  # Requested, set the root's password of MySQL service.
      - MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE=true
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql  # Requested, specifies the path to MySQL data persistent store.
    networks:
      - seafile-net

  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5.6
    container_name: seafile-memcached
    entrypoint: memcached -m 256
    networks:
      - seafile-net

  seafile:
    image: seafileltd/seafile-mc:latest
    container_name: seafile
    ports:
     - "1.1.1.1:80:80"
     - "1.1.1.1:443:443"  # If https is enabled, cancel the comment.
    volumes:
      - /opt/seafile-data:/shared   # Requested, specifies the path to Seafile data persistent store.
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_ROOT_PASSWD=11111111  # Requested, the value shuold be root's password of MySQL service.
      - TIME_ZONE=America/Recife  # Optional, default is UTC. Should be uncomment and set to your local time zone.
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL=email@gmail.com # Specifies Seafile admin user, default is 'me@example.com'.
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=01952265     # Specifies Seafile admin password, default is 'asecret'.
      - SEAFILE_SERVER_LETSENCRYPT=true   # Whether to use https or not.
      - SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME=cloud.felintonetwork.com # Specifies your host name if https is enabled.
    depends_on:
      - db
      - memcached
    networks:
      - seafile-net

networks:
  seafile-net:
```

ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', the service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'.

Comment: I tested the file and I don't get the error. Which command returns this error? Can you  post the output of `docker-compose config`?

Comment: I tried the command "docker-compose up -d". Being inside the directory where this file is.

Comment: Then maybe you did not save the file correctly. I see no other reason for the error

Comment: I have hidden some confidential data from the file. I think this is not the problem but I saved a file in pastebin lasting 1 day. You can try again >>> https://pastebin.com/raw/LP65xLpR
I checked and saved the file correctly yes.

Comment: Both files are missing a few characters at the beginning. Is that in your original file as well? Initially I thought it was a copy paste mistake but I now see it in the new file as well. Can you check?